# Youtube iFrame APi won't fire onPlayerStateChange function

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube-api

so I'm using the Youtube iFrame API to give me an alert when the video stops playing with the following code:

```
<div id="player"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var tag = document.createElement('script');

    tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

    var player;
    function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
      player = new YT.Player('player', {
          height: '390',
          width: '640',
          videoId: '0Bmhjf0rKe8',
          playerVars: {
              'autoplay': 1,
              'controls': 1,
              'html5': 1
          },
          events: {
              'onReady': onPlayerReady,
              'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }
      });
    }

      var playerReady = false;
      // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
      function onPlayerReady(event) {
          playerReady = true;

      }


      // 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
      //    The function indicates that when playing a video (state=1),
      //    the player should play for six seconds and then stop.
      function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
          if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
              alert('done');

          }
      }
```

I tried this same code on jsfiddle: (http://jsfiddle.net/QtBlueWaffle/8bpQ8/1/) and it *works fine* there. Doesn't work on my local machine though. Any ideas?

Comment: This might be a problem with the fact you are running locally. Have you tried putting the code on a webserver? Local pages usually have more restrictions with scripts and iFrames.

Comment: @Moustach you're right! Put it on a server and it works fine. Thanks for the catch!

Comment: I think you can run it on local machine but only with "https" and SSL certificate, if you can get it working